# Change widths of elements from 50% to 100% if array length is odd or even

Tags: javascript, css, pug

I want to show some elements(soundcloud widgets) to my page.

And depending of if they are `odd` or `even` they should have either `50%` or `100%` width.

Basically the rules i want to meet are:

-If there is only one element, make it 100% width

-If there are more than one element and the lenght of the array is even, make all elements 50%

-Otherwaays if the length of array is odd, make all but the very last one 50%, and the last one 100% width.

Im using pug, and cant figure out how to do this. maybe even flexbox could help here?

This is my code, the class `w-50` is setting the elements to 50% right now:

```
    each link in soundcloudEmbedableLinks
      .pb4.w-50.dib.pa2!=link
```

And this is how it looks now, all set to 50%.. but as I said i do want it to meet the rules i said above.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.myBox {
    width:50%;
}
.myBox:last-child {
    width:100%;
}
.myBox:nth-child(even) {
    width:50%;
}
```

The first rule sets the default to 50%, the second will set the last child to 100%, the 3rd will over-ride the second rule and set the last one back to 50% if it is even. This means all boxes will be 50% except for the last one if it is odd.

Comment: Thanks it worked, just had to change the last child rule to the botttom, if you fix that ill make the answer correct thanks so much!